# How can i make the Canvas in a event visible?

Tags: c#, wpf, computer-science

i have following problem, i want to generate a little canvas by a button click, after generating i want to move it by a key press event but i cant see the canvas in the event. How can i make it visible? (In the sourcecode of WPF not in XAML)

```
public void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    c.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
    c.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    c.Loaded += c_Loaded;
    Grid.Children.Add(c);

    Canvas ship = new Canvas();
    ship.Background = Brushes.Aquamarine;
    ship.Height = 30;
    ship.Width = 30;
    ship.KeyDown += ship_KeyDown;
    Canvas.SetTop(ship, 50);
    c.Children.Add(ship);  
}

void ship_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    canvas.Setleft(ship, canvas.Getleft(ship) +10);  //here i can not see the object "ship" :(          
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter sender:

```
Canvas ship = (Canvas) sender;
```

Comment: In the beginnig of ship_KeyDown

Comment: Parameter sender in ship_KeyDown is a reference to object (Canvas named ship) that you created in Button_Click_1

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add you c or ship to the layoutroot`

Comment: how can I add them to the layoutroot?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add it to a `<list>` of `UIElement` and modify it with a `foreach`-loop